# Java Spring Boot Batch - Need some advise in design

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am a newbie in Java and trying to implement a Spring Boot batch application.

My requirement is like to check some data in database (one part) and delete if found (another part).

I am planning to implement Spring Boot batch for this.

I will have one job which will have 2 steps. If Step 1 find some data then only execute step 2? Can I achieve in Spring Boot Batch? Or what is the best way to achieve this keeping in mind I have to schedule this to run weekly.

[image]

Comment: Is that a scheduled job or event driven job that you want to perform? Also, what's the expected volume of data you want to operate on?

Comment: @cosmos, what I heard the volume is huge. And it is a scheduled job

Comment: do you have approximate number on how huge the volume is? Spring Batch works in your design. I am just thinking, maybe it's not needed for such small scope unless volume of records to process is in millions.

Comment: @cosmos can we control the steps in spring batch? If so, how? Can u please give an example. I am not able to find anywhere.

Comment: @AmitKumar If its in spring-batch and java then you can check for the data in database and delete it and then you can launch your batch jobs.

Answer (score 2):

With just the scheduled job for find and delete records from DB, I don't suggest using Spring Batch. Spring has nice good way of doing it without Batch using scheduling-tasks. You can see [example here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/). Use Spring Batch only if you need to run jobs in batch that can't be handled with normal operation.

If you need complex scheduler, you can use [Spring Quartz scheduler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-quartz.html).